# How to check node table for entry by current date before inserting new node?

Tags: nodes

How can I check the database table for specific node entries by date before inserting a new node?

I want to check the node table for any node with the current date, if found, I want to delete the old one and insert a new node.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

Make a module and insert following code, switch "foo" with your module name.

```
    /**
    * Implements hook_node_presave($node).
    */
    function foo_node_presave($node) {
      // Lets search for nodes on the current date.
      $somedate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

      $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
      $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
      $query->propertyCondition('created', $somedate, '>=');
      $query->propertyCondition('created', $somedate + (60 * 60 * 24), '<');
      $result = $query->execute();

      if (!empty($result)) {
        node_delete_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
      }
    }
```

Obviously you might want to do some additional checks before deleting the nodes:

```
// Nodes of the same type
$query->propertyCondition('type', $node->type);

//Only delete published nodes
$query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Please let me know how to get the date from the node form field instead of taking current date.

Comment: You can access the date using the `$node` variable. Just do a print_r($node) or dpm($node) to see its contents, then convert the date value to a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion. Is there any hook which run when click on save/submit the node.

Comment: @rongok Please open a new question if you have a different question.